# Filter Item Listview whit TextField

Tags: flutter, bloc

Hello I have filled a ListView from list on my State Bloc(CustomerGetAllLoadedState) and work fine but now I need to search item from a TextField, I did so:

I declare list:

```
List<Customer> _customersFromRepo = [];
```

this is ListView where intercept to List Global:

```
                                           BlocBuilder<CustomerBloc, CustomerState>(
     builder: (context, state) {
       if (State is CustomerLoadingState) {
            return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                );
                                              }
     if (state is CustomerGetAllLoadedState) {
                                                
       _customersFromRepo = state.customers; // <----------- List for searh method


          return SizedBox(
          height: h * 0.5,
          width: w * 0.5,
          child: _customersFromRepo.isNotEmpty ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _customersFromRepo.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
```

key: ValueKey(
_customersFromRepo[index].id),

this is TextField for search items:

```
CustomTextFormField(
     txtLable: "Nome Cliente",
     onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value)
```

this is method fo filter:

```
 void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
List<Customer> results = [];
if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
  // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all users
  results = _customersFromRepo;
} else {
  results = _customersFromRepo
      .where(
          (customer) => customer.name.toString().toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
      .toList();
      }
setState(() {
  _customersFromRepo = results;
});
```

**But the list doesn't change even if _customersFromRepo has only one item, it always keeps the old state. Can I do?**

[image]

Comment: Can you share part of your code here where we can run it on dartpad?

Answer (score 0):

Update: So I changed the approach, filtered the list and then issued a block event with the List retrieved from the Filter and reissued the status loading all the Customers, Filter works but I have a problem when I fill in the word I need to search for it starts filtering **but if I go back it should unroll the filter but it doesn't:**

```
_runFilter(BuildContext context,String enteredKeyword) {
List<Customer> results = [];
if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
  // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all users
  results = _customersFromRepo;
} else {
  results = _customersFromRepo
      .where(
          (customer) => customer.name.toString().toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
      .toList();
      }
return context.read<CustomerBloc>().add(CustomerEventemitFilteredCustomer(results));
```

}

On thhe textField where input data for filter I used OnChane()

Answer (score 0):

I resolved Post My Solution all you. I have Loaded from Repository List for Filter,the result put in to Event and reloaded State with the filter.

```
    _runFilter(BuildContext context,String enteredKeyword) async{
    final List<Customer> customerd = await CustomerRepository(customerService: CustomerService()).getAllCustomers();
    List<Customer> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all users
      results = customerd;
    } else {results =


      customerd.where(
              (customer) => customer.name.toString().toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
          }

   context.read<CustomerBloc>().add(CustomerEventemitFilteredCustomer(results));

  }
```